# Session tied to user browser or IP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, session-variables

In ASP.NET is the session of a user tied to the user browser or IP address?  IIS keeps getting flooded with backup of requests and most of these requests come from same IP because it’s an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is "tied to the user browser".

The long answer is:

The session is typically identified based on a session id set in a cookie.

Alternatively, you can use cookieless sessions, where the session id is baked into the URL.

Anyone with access to the session id can use that session.